# Django multiple annotate with Sum get wrong answer

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I'm trying to use `.annotate()` with multiple `Sum()` But i got wrong calculations.
I've read that I should use `Subquery` but I didn't get it done with it maybe I use it in wrong way (because it is first time) or it doesn't solve my issue.

```
#managers.py

class DonationQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def completed(self):
        return self.with_donations_stats().filter(
            amount__lte=F('total_donation'), deleted_at=None)

    def not_completed(self):
        return self.with_donations_stats().filter(
            amount__gt=F('total_donation'), deleted_at=None)

    def with_donations_stats(self):
        return self.annotate(
            wallet_donation=Coalesce(Sum('wallet_transaction__amount'), 0),
            normal_donation=Coalesce(Sum('transactions__amount'), 0),
            total_donation=F('wallet_donation') + F('normal_donation'))


class DonationManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return DonationQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def completed(self):
        return self.get_queryset().completed()

    def not_completed(self):
        return self.get_queryset().not_completed()

    def with_donations_stats(self):
        return self.get_queryset().with_donations_stats()
```

```
#models.py

class Transaction(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.payment_id + ' - ' + self.status

    condition = models.ForeignKey('condition.Condition', related_name='transactions',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)

class WalletTransaction(AbstractBaseModel):
    condition = models.ForeignKey("condition.Condition", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='wallet_transaction', null=True)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}"

class Condition(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)  # .zfill(10)
    STATUS_PUBLISHED = "Published"
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_PUBLISHED, 'Published'),)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, db_index=True)

    donations = DonationManager()
```

and in my view i was querying for published conditions
conditions =

```
Condition.donations.filter(status=Condition.STATUS_PUBLISHED).with_donations_stats().order_by(
            '-id')
```

**UPDATE**
the final query is `SELECT "conditions"."id", "conditions"."user_id", "conditions"."association_id", "conditions"."nid", "conditions"."amount", "conditions"."donation", "conditions"."nid_type", "conditions"."first_name", "conditions"."father_name", "conditions"."last_name", "conditions"."nationality", "conditions"."gender", "conditions"."mobile", "conditions"."region", "conditions"."city", "conditions"."district", "conditions"."dob", "conditions"."introduction_file", "conditions"."disease_validation_file", "conditions"."medical_report_file", "conditions"."treatment_plan_file", "conditions"."cost_file", "conditions"."case_report_file", "conditions"."invoices_file", "conditions"."payment_file", "conditions"."generated_pdf_file", "conditions"."recovery_report_file", "conditions"."report_date", "conditions"."issued_place", "conditions"."specialization", "conditions"."disease_type", "conditions"."action_type", "conditions"."case_type", "conditions"."treatment_entity", "conditions"."accommodation_type", "conditions"."family_members", "conditions"."income_avg", "conditions"."medical_evaluation_status", "conditions"."researcher_opinion", "conditions"."rejection_reason", "conditions"."justification", "conditions"."insurance_company_name_ar", "conditions"."insurance_company_name_en", "conditions"."insurance_company_id", "conditions"."insurance_beneficiary_number", "conditions"."insurance_beneficiary_type", "conditions"."insurance_class", "conditions"."insurance_expiry", "conditions"."insurance_limit", "conditions"."insurance_policy", "conditions"."status", "conditions"."created_at", "conditions"."updated_at", "conditions"."published_at", "conditions"."deleted_at", "conditions"."image", "conditions"."last_donation_at", COALESCE((SELECT SUM(U0."amount") AS "amount_sum" FROM "wallets_wallettransaction" U0 WHERE U0."condition_id" = ("conditions"."id") GROUP BY U0."id" ORDER BY U0."id" DESC  LIMIT 1), 0) AS "wallet_donation", COALESCE((SELECT SUM(U0."amount") AS "amount_sum" FROM "transactions" U0 WHERE U0."condition_id" = ("conditions"."id") GROUP BY U0."condition_id"  LIMIT 1), 0) AS "normal_donation", (COALESCE((SELECT SUM(U0."amount") AS "amount_sum" FROM "wallets_wallettransaction" U0 WHERE U0."condition_id" = ("conditions"."id") GROUP BY U0."id" ORDER BY U0."id" DESC  LIMIT 1), 0) + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(U0."amount") AS "amount_sum" FROM "transactions" U0 WHERE U0."condition_id" = ("conditions"."id") GROUP BY U0."condition_id"  LIMIT 1), 0)) AS "total_donation" FROM "conditions" WHERE "conditions"."status" = Published ORDER BY "conditions"."id" DESC`

Note: and I'm using the same annotation in another view resulting the same thing.

Comment: Show your attempts with the subqueries... (Also you don't show enough information in your question `wallet_transaction`, `transactions`, should be some related models in that case you should show at least _some_ of their relevant code and also show your model for which you write this manager)

Comment: I've added some wallet_transaction and transactions models and also added the query which I use the annotation and get the wrong sum. In my opinion let we ignore my attempts with subquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have stumbled upon the problem that [Combining multiple aggregations [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) will [yield the wrong results](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060) because joins are used instead of subqueries.

Since to make aggregations over relations Django makes joins and with aggregation on multiple relations there would be multiple joins the results of course are wrong. Therefore we need to annotate using [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery


class DonationQuerySet(QuerySet):
    ...
    
    def with_donations_stats(self):
        # Subquery for wallet donation
        # Added order_by because it appears you have some default ordering
        wallet_donation = WalletTransaction.objects.filter(
            condition=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by().values('condition').annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount')).values('amount_sum')[:1]
        
        # Subquery for normal donation
        normal_donation = Transaction.objects.filter(
            condition=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('condition').annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount')).values('amount_sum')[:1]
        
        return self.annotate(
            wallet_donation=Coalesce(Subquery(wallet_donation), 0),
            normal_donation=Coalesce(Subquery(normal_donation), 0),
            total_donation=F('wallet_donation') + F('normal_donation')
        )
```

Comment: I noticed that `wallet_donation` value always return the latest donation amount not the sum

Comment: I've copied the `with_donations_stats()` as it it is working fine with the `normal_donation` I reviewed it with the database it is working but I noticed that the `wallet_donation` return the last amount added to the condition in the `WalletTransaction` table as I noted I am using the `with_donations_stats()` in the `Condition.donations.filter(status=Condition.STATUS_PUBLISHED).with_donations_stats().order_by(
            '-id')` no more what do you think ?

Comment: @AhmedSamy can you add the output of `print(queryset.query)` and your exact queryset code to your question? (With `queryset` being the query you are making)

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233963/discussion-between-ahmed-samy-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).

Comment: Aziz Barajat cart_donation = Cart.objects.filter(
            transaction_id__isnull=True,
            condition=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('condition').annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount'), output_field=IntegerField()).values('amount_sum')[:1] --get me error QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>.

Comment: @AhmedSamy instead of `annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount'), output_field=IntegerField()` put the output field in the `Sum` function itself: `annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount', output_field=IntegerField())`.

Comment: I will start implementing another solution but I need to avoid Race conditions. I cant use select for update. Is F() expression enough to handle it?.  Note the server some times get so high load and it causes race condition many times.