# Django sum of a particular field for some distinct column

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a table **OrderTransaction** which has foreign key for table **Order**. I want to calculate the outstanding amount i.e. the amount for which transaction has not yet occurred. To calculate that I first need to calculate the total amount (Order table has field total amount) so that I can subtract the amount of transaction that has taken place from it. I am grouping by the the query by *recorded_by* field because I need to know what salesman has collected how much amount. Following is my query.

```
order_transaction_qs
.exclude(recorded_by=None)
.order_by("recorded_by")
.values("recorded_by")
.annotate(
    cash_in_hand=Coalesce(
        Sum("amount", filter=Q(payment_method=PaymentMethod.CASH_ON_DELIVERY)), Value(0)
    ),
    cheque=Coalesce(
        Sum("amount", filter=Q(payment_method=PaymentMethod.CHEQUE)), Value(0)
    ),
    others=Coalesce(
        Sum(
            "amount",
            filter=~Q(
                payment_method__in=[
                    PaymentMethod.CHEQUE,
                    PaymentMethod.CASH_ON_DELIVERY,
                ]
            ),
        ),
        Value(0),
    ),
    order_amount=Sum(
        "order__total_amount"
    ),  # NOTE: Multiple transactions on same orders will give extra amount.
    outstanding=ExpressionWrapper(
        F("order_amount") - (F("cash_in_hand") + F("cheque") + F("others")),
        output_field=FloatField(),
    ),
)
```

The problem with above query is that if there are multiple transaction for same order, it is adding the total_amount multiple times.
Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong results because joins are used instead of subqueries according to the django docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

This post shares a solution to a similar problem: [Django multiple annotate with Sum get wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68047322/django-multiple-annotate-with-sum-get-wrong-answer)